# Ways to resize images before upload to Odoo

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, odoo

Is there a way to **resize images** being uploaded and added to **Odoo** records before they're stored on the db **(on the front end side)**:

I realize we can do this on the backend side but **a more optimal way** is to do it **before record creation**:

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    if 'image' in values:
        # resize uploaded image into 250 X 250
        resize_image = tools.image_resize_image(values['image'], size=(250, 250), avoid_if_small=True)
        values['image'] = resize_image
    return super(YourModelName, self).create(values)
```

Comment: Your code example is maybe just a little example, but calling super only when there is `image` in the values is probably a bit suboptimal ;-)

Comment: the indentation got messed up when I pasted the snippet here haha!

Comment: But to your question: If you want to do that, you have to change Odoo's frontend JS Code. A way to do that, would probably be extending `FieldBinaryImage` (Odoo 13) and adding some options to it, like max-width and max-height or something like that. If you never have done such extensions [this would be a good starting point](https://github.com/OCA/web/blob/13.0/web_widget_image_download/static/src/js/web_widget_image_download.js).